# ngAnimation and ngRepeat to change all item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm showing a simple list using ngRepeat.
When a button click is triggered, I need to change all old items in my list and then show the new ones.
I'd like to do it using some kind of animation (could be opacity, height or whatever).
Is it possible to do all old items disapear before start adding the new ones.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lyk6Lqe5/2/

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" >
    <button ng-click="changeAll()">Change</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="item" ng-repeat="i in myList">{{i}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngAnimate'])
MyApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.list_a = ["Item A","Item B","Item C"];
    $scope.list_b = ["Item D","Item E","Item F", "Item G"];
    $scope.myList = $scope.list_a;

    $scope.changeAll = function(){
        $scope.myList = $scope.myList.length == 3 ? $scope.list_b : $scope.list_a;
    }
}]);
```

CSS

```
.item.ng-enter,
.item.ng-leave{
    transition:all 1s ease;
}

.item.ng-enter,
.item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active{
    opacity:0;
}

.item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.item.ng-leave{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is kind of hacky, but works. It is to set the array to empty, timeout, and then set the array once the old array has been removed. You will need to inject $timeout. The only other way I can think of is to do the same thing, but wait for a transitionend event rather than relying on a fixed timeout.

```
$scope.changeAll = function(){
    var oldList = $scope.myList;
    $scope.myList = [];
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.myList = oldList.length == 3 ? $scope.list_b : $scope.list_a;
    }, 900);
}
```

Here is a --[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/Lyk6Lqe5/3/)--

Comment: Well, it isn't the best answer I'd expect, but it helps. Many thanks